# PHP/PDO: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a code that for an unknown reason crashes the following error:

**sendToken.php file**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once("../config/config.php");
require_once("admin.php");
require_once("helper.php");
$helper = new helper();
if(isset($_POST['client_database_id'])){
$cldbid = $_POST['client_database_id'];
    $verification_code = rand(1000, 9999);
    $clientList = $helper->clientList();
    foreach($clientList as $client){
        if($cldbid==$client['client_database_id']){
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ts_users` WHERE cldbid=:cldbid");
            $sql->execute(['cldbid'=> $client['client_database_id']]);
            $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($row['verificated']&&$row['activated']){
                header('Location: /new/');
            }else if($row['verificated']&&!$row['activated']){
                header('Location: /setpass');
            }else{
                $result = [
                    'success'=> true,
                    'message'=> [
                        'cldbid'=> $client['client_database_id'],
                        'code'=> $verification_code,
                        'nickname'=> $client['client_nickname'],
                        'message'=> 'Wpisz Token wysłany na Serwerze!'
                    ]
                ];
                $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `ts_users` (cldbid, verification_code) VALUES (:cldbid, :verification_code)");
                $sql->execute(['cldbid'=> $client['client_database_id'], 'verification_code'=> $verification_code]);
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    $result = [
        'success'=> false,
        'message'=> 'Brak Parametru: client_database_id!'
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

**config.php file**

```
//$config = [];
$config['general'] = [
    'connection' => [
        //Config Database
        'database' => [
            'host' => 'localhost', //IP Bazy Danych
            'user' => 'root', //Login do Bazy Danych
            'password' => '', //Haslo do Bazy Danych
            'databaseName' => 'xFiveBOT', //Nazwa Bazy Danych
        ],
    ],
];
```

**admin.php file**

```
$connect = $config['general']['connection'];
if(!isset($pdo)){
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$connect['database']['host'].";dbname=".$connect['database']['databaseName'], $connect['database']['user'], $connect['database']['password'], [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $message = [
            'message'=> [
                'access'=> false,
                'error'=> false,
                'message'=> 'Błąd Łaczenia z Bazą Danych.',
            ]
        ];
        echo json_encode($message);
    }
}
```

And I am getting this error message when I run the PHP file containing the PHP code above:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Why this happens?

P.S. Of course, when I comment this line: //header("Content-type: application/json"); the error message disappears

Comment: Can you include the JSON being generated / failing to parse?

Comment: I always get this error when I perform a json AJAX call and the return value is not valid JSON data. I then use the browsers developer tools to check what json was generated. Most of the time there's a simple error message there (when error reporting is switched on).

Comment: @Gavin {"success":false,"message":"Brak Parametru: client_database_id!"}

Comment: @Gavin https://hastebin.com/puboxohiga.xml

Comment: That certainly looks fine. Try changing the success handler to take inputs: `success: function(data, textStatus, xhr)` and console.log the xhr.responseText. This should show you the text responded by the request before any attempts at parsing is made. Hopefully more clues there.

Comment: @Gavin POST http://xfiveplay.pl/new/auth/sendToken 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @DEVDJ That's the problem then. The server side code is breaking so not sending JSON as expected. Unfortunately 500 is a bit generic but you should be able to step though it and see where it's getting upset.

Comment: @Gavin You know, when I didn't have a database connection in this file and there was only a php code to receive and send, it all worked flawlessly but when I added require_once with the configuration and connection to the database, I have this error

Comment: Error reporting should be able to tell where it bugs, also activate php INI display_errors and xdebug for easier debug

Comment: Thinking something is wrong with the redirect pages we can't see. You can enable errors by using `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the first line of your script file(s).

Comment: @ThanhTrung When I upload the configuration code and admin.php file to the page and I won't use it, there are no errors

Comment: Check the encoding of the document (i.e. the PHP source code) is not anything strange. It should be UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, or ASCII. Chances are there's a BOM or similar before the JSON content.

Comment: Also you should edit your question to include the response you're getting, instead of leaving it in comments. Your response is completely different from the code you've provided, by the way...